# How to pass a variable to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arduino-c++

I am trying to pass a String variable to a function but its throwing an error

> no matching function for call to 'AsyncWebServer::on(String&,
> WebRequestMethod, processor(const
> String&)::<lambda(AsyncWebServerRequest*)>)'

The reason is because I`m trying to pass variable **r** to a function, but when I pass to a function some **string in quotes""** it works just fine.

**NOT** works :

```
String r = randString();
server.on(r , HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false);
});
```

works :

```
server.on("/jjj", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false, processor);
});
```

Comment: A literal string is a `const char *`, which is not a `String` object. Check if `String` has a method that returns a `const char *` or `char *`. Also check if `server::on` requires its first argument to be valid after the call or not.

Comment: your two example do not only differ by how the string is passed, but also the `send` call in the lambda is different (note the extra `processor`), which might result in an incompatible return type of the lambda

Comment: Check the params type of server.on function and then pass the data as required .

Cast the data to the required type. It may work.

Comment: @root_coding And make sure the cast is valid.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
String r = randString();
r = "/" + r;
const char* b = r.c_str();

server.on(b , HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false);
});
```

Comment: The "solution" seems to be simply using `c_str()` to begin with. There is no `String` in C++, that's likely provided by whatever library/SDK you are using. There is, however, `std::string`, which may be usable in this context where `String` isn't.

Comment: assuming `String::c_str()` returns a `char const*`, the expression `"/" + r.c_str()` is attempting to add two `char const*` which won't compile.

Comment: Sorry guys, I changed it to working version. @Rogue